# Ajax post form - how to resubmit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

So I have the following form, with an ajax, which to call the server for user authentication. Now the problem is that let's say the user password is wrong. If the user tries to correct it any subsequent call does no longer trigger the `on('submit')` function thus he is stuck at the page. How can I make it to allow resubmition of the form?

```js
var login_email = document.getElementById("login_email");
var login_password = document.getElementById("login_password");

$(function() {
    $('form#login_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        console.log("submit");
        $.post('/auth_user', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data == "No user registered with this email.") {
                login_email.setCustomValidity(data);
            } else if(data == "Incorrect password.") {
                login_password.setCustomValidity(data);
            } else {

            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/dashboard" id="login_form" method="post">
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="login_email" required autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            Password<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="login_password" required autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                    <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"/>Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: instead of using `$('form#login_form').on('submit', function(e)` have you considered using the submit function? like this `$('form#login_form').submit(function(e)...`

Comment: Hmm, based on the code you showed us, I don't see any reason for any subsequent ajax call to never fire... Your 'console.log("submit")' never logs to the console after the first try?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but suggest you change your error prompts to "invalid username or password" regardless of which was wrong.  Based on the output of your code, a hacker will be able to tell when they hit a valid username and only have to brute force the password.  Do that in the auth_user call on the server as well.

Comment: Yes only the first time, after that it also always pops the validity message, but I never get any subsequent console logs. I thought it could be related to `e.preventDefault();` but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness good point!

Comment: Interestingly enough when I did something minimal on Jfiddle it works: https://jsfiddle.net/j0w6knoe/ . Any ideas what can cause it not to work?

Comment: that (class="req") suggest there may be another submit handler somewhere that is getting in your way.  As long as the customvalidity is anything but an empty string element.valid is going to be false.

Comment: Is it possible to display a validity message just as hover until the user types smth in?

Comment: Add an onchange handler to the input to setcustomvalidity=""

Comment: @ChrisCaviness that worked! If you make a short answer I will accept it.
 Can I ask if you could answer, for some reason the customValidity pop ups come out on the next press of submit (e.g. submit invalid -> I get a log, but no pop up, submit a second time->pop up shows). I think somehow it  gets delayed/not draw, any idea how/why?

Comment: This would be because validation isn't tested UNTIL submit is called.  I would suggest "preflighting" your validation ajax on the onchange events for the username/password fields and setcustomvalidate there to the error message, then when submit is pressed it's ready to go with either an error message or form submit.  Not sure if what I said above is clear.  You press submit, no validation failures, gets to your onsubmit, you set a validation problem and stop submit.  Next submit, validation fails because of your change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer... from discussion above.

Move the credential authentication ajax to the onchange event for both email and password and set a customvalidation message to "invalid username or password" or "" depending on ajax result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding a type submit attribute to your html button tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/dashboard" id="login_form" method="post">
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="login_email" required autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            Password<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="login_password" required autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                    <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"/>Log In</button>
</form>
```

Also you need not put a listener for submit you can use the `.submit()` function of jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('form#login_form').submit(function(e) {
        console.log("submit");
        $.post('/auth_user', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data == "No user registered with this email.") {
                login_email.setCustomValidity(data);
            } else if(data == "Incorrect password.") {
                login_password.setCustomValidity(data);
            } else {

            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The other way is you put a click handler on the button and internally call the .submit() for the form

Comment: Good suggestions, but still any subsequent button press does not trigger the function.